# my hayward electric spa heater isn't heating as well

Tags: water-heater

The 2 elements when taken out, test at 10 ohms each, but when one is inserted in heater and wired, it still tests 10 ohms at screws, but when 2nd in also inserted and wired to thermostat, the ohms reading at screws on both elements only reads 5 ohms.  Does the thermostat need to be replaced?

Comment: Did you mean "on both elements" or "on each element"? Resistance would be lower if you're measuring both in parallel.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide the exact model number, too. That will help in trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the elements are properly installed they are in parallel. 2 10 ohm resistors in parallel is equal to 5 ohms so your elements are wired in parallel and this is the normal way to wire them.

If you want to learn more read up on Ohms law

The calculation 1/RT= 1/R1 + 1/R2

RT is total resistance for parallel resistances.

R1 is heater 1 resistance value

R2 is heater 2 resistance value.

So 10 ohms in parallel with 10 ohms is 5 ohms

Comment: okay, thanks so much. But my  other concern is the 220 wiring cord to the heater after these 10 years of use is now to hot to touch after running 8 hours of use.

Comment: Two hot to touch is not right the wires don’t break down unless abused but the connections may have issues at the connection points. Just the heater draws 24 + 10 amps for a 1 Hp pump at 240 so that alone would require #8 wire and possibly #6 if a 50 amp breaker was required. What size wire is connecting the tub? What is the breaker size? Are the pump(s) running / sound normal.

Comment: Thanks again. The wire is #8 which goes 42 feet from breaker box to 50 amp groundfault breaker at heater core.  50 amp breaker switch has been thrown 3 times last month shutting off the heater. The pumps sound fine but pressure guage had gone from 12 to 15 indicating need for back flush which was done. We have thought about running a #6 wire through pvc pipe attached to ceiling( current wire is through rafters in finished ceiling) to redo things for safety sake.

Comment: and motor is a 1 1/2 hp hayward.

Comment: If on a 50 and your wires are hot you should have #6. Aging pumps with the bearings getting old do draw more amperage, it could also being a capacitor on the motor starting to fail so the motor is drawing more.  If the answers and comments were helpful upvoting will help others to find them and if you accept (the check mark) people will know this was useful information. I see you added a 1-1/2hp motor info while I was typing. This motor is 10 amp draw sized at 12.5, any air pumps or lights that would definitely put you in the +40 amp class

Answer (score 1):

### Because you're measuring *the whole circuit*!

I'm sure you'd agree the measurement on the left is correct.

[image: schematic]

So why does the right side read the same?

The wires connect all those points with an extremely low-resistance path.   So even though you are *trying to point to* only one resistor with the probes... the wires connect it to the other resistor *whether you like it or not*.

If you connected the left probe to *anywhere along those wires left of the resistors, you'd get the same thing again.

This is the inherent problem with *in-circuit* testing of components.  The component must be isolated to get a true reading.